# ShellExecute occupies directory

Tags: c++, winapi

My C++ program is in a directory (`A`). After running `ShellExecute()` through this program, I open an application XShell, close my C++ program, and then I find that in the resource monitor, the `A` directory is occupied by the program XShell I enabled. How to solve it?

```
ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", L"D:\\Program Files\\NetSarang\\Xshell 6\\Xshell.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT)
```

[image]

After the C++ program exits, XShell occupies my C++ program directory.

I hope that after opening an application through `ShellExecute()`, this application does not occupy the directory of the C++ program.

Answer (score 3):

The directory is occupied because the secondary program is inheriting that directory as its *working directory*. To avoid that, you can specify the desired working directory that the secondary program should use in the `lpDirectory` parameter of `ShellExecuteW()`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew

> `[in, optional] lpDirectory`
>
> Type: `LPCTSTR`
>
> A pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the default (working) directory for the action. If this value is `NULL`, the current working directory is used. If a relative path is provided at *lpFile*, do not use a relative path for *lpDirectory*.

For example, you can specify `"C:\\"` (which should always exist and be accessible).